# Can someone tell me what is the meaning for below code snippet

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

Can someone explain to me what is happening with the below code snippet

```
//Creating New Contact Record
    public void createNewContact() {
        wrapperList = createNewContact(wrapperList);
    }
    public List<WrapperClass> createNewContact (List<WrapperClass> insertList) {
        WrapperClass newRecord = new WrapperClass();
        Contact newContactRecord = new Contact();
        newContactRecord.AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        newRecord.con = newContactRecord;
        insertList.add(newRecord);
        return insertList;
    }
```

Comment: It adds a new row on the list of contacts in the page so that a new contact can be added to the account. What part is confusing about this?

Comment: If you don't mind can you explain each line of the code snippet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void createNewContact() {
    // Calls method with parameter, and pointlessly reassigns back to list
    wrapperList = createNewContact(wrapperList);
}
public List<WrapperClass> createNewContact (List<WrapperClass> insertList) {
    // Creates a new wrapper that will display a new entry on the page.
    WrapperClass newRecord = new WrapperClass();
    // Creates a record in memory for user input.
    Contact newContactRecord = new Contact();
    // Sets the AccountId from the page's URL. ?id=001...
    newContactRecord.AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    // Puts the contact in to the wrapper.
    newRecord.con = newContactRecord;
    // Adds the wrapper to the list of wrappers
    insertList.add(newRecord);
    // Returns the value back to the caller.
    return insertList;
}
```

Most of this code is fluff, unnecessary. Here's an optimized version:

```
public void createNewContact() {
    // Creates a new wrapper that will display a new entry on the page.
    WrapperClass wrapper = new WrapperClass();
    // Creates a record in memory for user input.
    wrapper.con = new Contact(
        // Sets the AccountId from the page's URL. ?id=001...
        AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
    );
    // Adds the wrapper to the list of wrappers
    wrapperList.add(newRecord);
}
```

Other optimizations may be possible, such as modifying WrapperClass to automatically initialize the contact record, etc.

Comment: Thankyou It helped me a lot.